# Why 777 cause problem but 644 was fine

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a VPS, for some reason php can only exec when permission is 644.

If I changed the php file to 777 or 755, it would throw me an Error 500 internal server error.

I thought 777 give everybody greatest permission, what makes a web server behave like that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8):

This is done for the same reason that `sshd` won't log you in if your `.ssh` directory is too widely writable.

How does your server know it is really your application if anyone could have changed it?

Comment: i.e. it's a feature

Comment: i.e. Thank you PHP for preventing me from doing something idiotic (no offense).

Answer (score 2):

> I thought 777 give everybody greatest permission, what makes a web server behave like that?

777 means everybody can read write and execute your www directory. Do you really want people to create "any" files and execute?

Of course not. One of the security 101 principle is principle of least privilege. Basically that means giving a user only those powers which are absolutely essential to do his/her work.

Answer (score 1):

Your webserver might have "suexec" enabled by default. Suexec is very particular about 644 and does not allows file with permissions 755 or 777 to work. You can read about suexec and its pros and cons here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/suexec.html